# Night-blooming Jasmine (cestrum nocturnum) leaves are being eatin by something!

Tags: bugs

My Night-blooming Jasmine (cestrum nocturnum) leaves are being eatin by something. Anyone know what it could be and how to avoid this?
[image]
[image: Night-blooming Jasmine (cestrum nocturnum) leaves are being eatin by something]

Answer (score 5):

Looks remarkably like caterpillar damage - check the plant all over for signs of them, or leaf hoppers, and take a torch out at night and check then. Also inspect the backs of the leaves for signs of invaders resident there, though they won't be caterpillars.

Comment: Could also be slugs. Check for them at night and also hiding in shady spots or under leaves and mulch during the day.